# How to cite AI generated images in a presentation?

Tags: citations, presentation, generative-ai

I’m making a presentation, and wanted to use some images from an AI tool as sort of stock imagery. How would I properly cite them? I’m making them myself using Midjourney, but could find no guidance on this. I would also be curious if that’s different from images made with other models such as a public open source Stable Diffusion model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that in the short term it is best if you just name the tool(s) you used. Longer term there may still be a question about who/what the creator of such an image should be. Where does any "creativity" lie?

I'll note that in the US, at least, the copyright office of the government has decided that AI generated images can't be copyrighted, implying that the AI itself isn't a creator. Whether creativity will be attributed to the person directing the AI, when that happens, might still be an open question.

But you lose nothing by mentioning your tools, in any case.

Comment: Gratefully thanking our soon-to-be AI Overlords might curry some favor...

Answer (score 0):

The authorship and citation quagmire will remain with us for some times to come. Until then, we continue with principle of ethics.

> making them myself using Midjourney, ... I would also be curious if that’s different from images made with other models such as a public open source Stable Diffusion model.

Irrespective of `Midjourney`, `Leonardo.ai`, or even `visualgpt`making extensive use of `Stable Diffusion` under the hood, the question remains, *who is the author/owner*.

For now, one might play it safe with

- ... *image generated by author through AI generation using [tool]* ...
- *image AI generated by author using [tool]*

This approach will not be far off from how we handle Tables and visual representation of models/concepts that we use in our manuscript.